# Regex is possible to match?

Tags: regex, match, digits

I have files with these filename:

```
ZATR0008_2018.pdf
ZATR0018_2018.pdf
ZATR0218_2018.pdf
```

Where the 4 digits after `ZATR` is the issue number of magazine.

With this regex:

```
([1-9][0-9]*)(?=_\d)
```

I can extract `8`, `18` or `218` but I would like to keep minimum 2 digits and max 3 digits so the result should be `08`, `18` and `218`.

How is possible to do that?

Comment: What kind of regex is your app expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
0*(\d{2,3})_\d
```

and grab Group 1 value. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jg0Y1t/1).

**Details**

- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
- `(\d{2,3})` - Group 1: two or three digits
- `_\d` - a `_` followed with a digit.

Here is a PCRE variation that grabs the value you need into a whole match:

```
0*\K\d{2,3}(?=_\d)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jg0Y1t/2)

Here, `\K` makes the regex engine omit the text matched so far (zeros) and then matches 2 to 3 digits that are followed with `_` and a digit.

Comment: Hi Wiktor also your solution works. I modified it in this way: (\D{2})(\D{2})(?:0*)(\d{2,3})(?=_\d) Using $2$3 I can re-assemble the tokens. Thanks Wiktor.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:[1-9][0-9]?)?[0-9]{2}(?=_[0-9])
```

or perhaps:

```
(?:[1-9][0-9]+|[0-9]{2})(?=_[0-9])
```

(https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html, which claims to use the XRegExp library, that you mention in another answer doesn't seem to backtrack into the `(?:)?` in my first suggestion where necessary, which makes it very different from any regex engine I've encoutered before and makes it prefer to match just the `18` of `218` even though it starts later in the string.  But it does work with my second suggestion.

Comment: Hi ysth because I'm beginner of regex I would like to know how (and if is possibile) to make your solution "a group". I mean in search and replace with regex is possible to do something like that: if string is for example ZATR0008_2018.pdf and regex is (\D{4})(\d{4})(_\d{4})(.pdf) I can re-assemble the tokens like $1$3$4 for result of ZATR_2018.pdf But how I can define your (?:[1-9][0-9]+|[0-9]{2})(?=_[0-9]) a single group that can be used to replace?

Comment: just add () around the whole thing or remove the `?:`

Answer (score 0):

```
([1-9]\d{2,3})(?=_\d)
```

{x,y} will match from x to y times the previous pattern, in this case \d

Edit: from your own regex it looked as you wanted the part of the number which starts with a non-zero. However since your examples include leading 0s, maybe you really wanted :

```
   (\d{2,3})(?=_\d)
```

Which will give you the last 3 digits before underscore unless there are only 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you:

```
^ZATR0*(\d{2,3})_\d+\.pdf$
```

demo code [here](https://regex101.com/r/MZ0vRi/1/). Result:

> Match 1 Full match    0-17    `ZATR0008_2018.pdf` Group 1.    6-8 `08`
>
> Match 2 Full match    18-35   `ZATR0018_2018.pdf` Group 1.    24-26   `18`
>
> Match 3 Full match    36-53   `ZATR0218_2018.pdf` Group 1.    41-44   `218`

Comment: Thanks Tommaso to point me in the right direction. But If I would like to match only digits (without groups) example 08, 18 218?

Comment: I need to pass the regex in an app to extract my issue (08, 18, 218 like the example). I dont'have field like saerch and replace where i can define $1, $2 like groups. So I need to identify and match the issue.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo sounds like the app takes a regex, not the results of a regex, and the entire regex needs to match just the desired digits.  I tried to do that in my answer